# Auto increment id based on last entry rather than first blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I have a users and an assets table (postgres backend), when a user creates a new asset it populates the asset id as expected 1, 2, 3, etc. which is displayed as ###1 based on our current asset tagging method.

As part of the asset management system we need to import assets that have been exported from our current system. I'm using roo and find_by_or_initialize to create these assets using their current id. However when I go to add a new asset it uses the first free id and uses that instead of using the next in the sequence. This wouldn't be an issue but there about 200 missing numbers in the existing management system and I can't think of a solution other than manually adding them at the moment.

Is there a way to make the id not use the first blank for instance; 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12?

This is the create method for the assets

```
def create
  @asset = current_user.assets.build(params[:asset])
   if @asset.save
    redirect_to root_path
    flash.now[:success] = "Asset created!"
  else
   render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

This is the method used to import existing assets

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    asset = find_or_initialize_by_id(spreadsheet.cell(i, 'A')) || new
    asset.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    asset.save!
  end
end
```

EDIT:
And this is an example of the current behaviour
[image: Asset Manager]

Comment: i dont get your question

Comment: I've updated the question to show the current behaviour, because there is no asset with the id currently set to 1 it automatically uses that instead of moving to 11 as I'd hoped

Comment: If you created a sequence in `postgre` then you could try using   `set_sequence_name "your_postgree_seq_here"` in your Assest model.

Comment: Following on from what you said I realised I could simply restart the existing ID sequence to the last value I'll be importing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a think about it and taken some advice from some people on reddit and have realised the logical solution is to restart the postgres sequence for `asset_id_seq` to the last value in the existing management system.

I've included the relevant commands for this situation;

```
asset_development=# alter sequence assets_id_seq restart with 1479;
ALTER SEQUENCE
asset_development=# \d assets_id_seq
        Sequence "public.assets_id_seq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | assets_id_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 1479
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | f
Owned by: public.assets.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is critically important to have sequential numbers, then you could do it the old-fashioned way. Disable auto-increment, store the last number in some special table somewhere, then increment and re-save that number every time you need a new one.

Or, you could just do something like SELECT MAX(id) FROM ASSETS ...

Be careful though, there are a few really good reasons to have the DB auto-increment and not just roll your own.